# Kiosk mode Ubuntu

Tags: autostart, kiosk, restricted-access

We have a few Windows 10 kiosk computers in the hallway. I want to replace them with an Ubuntu image.

A few things I've managed so far:

- Users can log in automatically.
- The browser starts at login.

A few things I'm still figuring out:

- How to prevent users from doing things, like disabling the network connection (or changing any settings at all).
- How to autostart the browser when they close it.

I know how these can be done on Windows. How can I achieve them with Ubuntu?

Comment: Thanks but: upstart-sysv doesn't work anymore, sudoedit /etc/init/kiosk.conf gives file or directory doesn't excist. I'll give it another try tomorrow.

Comment: Did you take a look at https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/secure-ubuntu-kiosk which seems to be a tutorial on how to Kiosk Mode in 18.04?  It's heavily Snap driven though, so you'll have to build your own Kiosk snap.  It links to guides on that elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I am still researching details, but this works for basic requirements that you posted.

```
# I started with just Ubuntu Server, so first install basic Xorg packages
apt-get install xserver-xorg-core -y
# next install openbox, it is pretty basic window manager
apt-get install openbox -y
# install xinit and Chromium, you can pick your browser but pls don't ask me details for them
apt-get install xinit -y
apt-get install chromium -y
# setup autologin so it acts as a kiosk
mkdir /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/
nano /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/override.conf
    [Service]
    Type=simple
    ExecStart=
    ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin YourUsername --noclear %I 38400 linux
# create or modify .profile script in your /home/YopurUsername to start X on login
nano .profile
    #Startx Automatically
    if [[ -z "$DISPLAY" ]] && [[ $(tty) = /dev/tty1 ]]; then
        . startx
        logout
    fi
# in same location create or edit .xinitrc which will start your browser, eg, Chromium
nano .xinitrc
    #!/bin/sh
    xset -dpms
    xset s off
    xset s noblank
    # the following starts Chromium in kiosk/fullscreen and forces FullHD size, disables bunch of toolbars and features etc; modify this or hte Chromium profile to lock it down to your liking, but that's more a question on it's own
    chromium https://www.bing.com --window-size=1920,1080 --start-fullscreen --kiosk --incognito --noerrdialogs --disable-translate --no-first-run --fast --fast-start --disable-infobars --disable-features=TranslateUI --disk-cache-dir=/dev/null  --password-store=basic
reboot
```

What I've found is:

- This will autologin as YourUser
- Will start Xorg and initialize openbox with almost zero bells and whistles
- Will start Chromium in fullscreen
- If someone close Chromium it will restart immediately (will see short shell, but not enough to interact)
- Chromium won't have addresbar, bookmarks, and so on, so most options will be unavailable right from there
- Optionally start Chromium in incognito flag to avoid saving sessions
- Use unclutter if you want to remove the mouse cursor from screen (or hide it after idle=x seconds)

This is hardly a full blown solution, but it's a good start, and can be used as-is. My own plan is to PXE Boot, then make a web management where I can reboot the kiosks or change their URLs and stuff. If I ever make it a full tutorial I'll edit this with a link :)